# Why don't Jews farm in the USA?

Tags: history, agriculture, jewish-american-history

A quick and easy check on locations of Orthodox synagogues in the USA reveals they are only clustered in very high-density populated urban areas. Places where antisemitism is high, where Constitutional rights of individual Americans are more restricted, high crime, high drug abuse, gang activity on the doorstep, high food and housing prices, on and on.

The safest area I've seen a synagogue in was Portland in 2011, and we saw what that became in 2020. There was one Jewish farmer at that synagogue, who lived a little ways out and commuted to the shul before Shabbos with his family in an RV every week.

In many rural areas there are Amish families, far more isolated and insulated that Jewish families, and they thrive.  People accept them just fine. Muslims are sometimes in the community and are also accepted. Hollywood seems to perpetuate a number of myths about people in farming communities. Those stereotypes only exist in movies now.

It wouldn't even take 100 families with creatively-arranged acre plots, some even running small farms, to setup an eruv, synagogue, mikveh. And in these areas there are slaughter houses serving adjoining counties who would likely work with a small kosher slaughter house for selling the non-kosher meat that inevitably is produced. Not a lot of dining choices, but a family could easily eat kosher from the grocery store. Chabad centers are usually close by at the nearest university.

There are so many agrarian mitzvot you could do here that are impossible in the high rise of Flat Bush or wherever. Such a better quality of life. And since Noahides were often devout Christians, you're likely to find them there.

So why don't Jews farm (or live in farm-capable areas)? Even if you didn't farm, the quality of life is so much better in those areas. Why not?

Comment: I'm not sure this is on-topic.

Comment: Seems in line with the hits that show up in the "Related" side bar.

Comment: Hard to make a living as a farmer especially with the high costs of Jewish life... Kosher food, education, holidays, and ritual items

Comment: Also, devout Christians have a tendency to strongly encourage their employees to be Christians. Jews prefer not to leave the cities because there can be a critical mass of them to fight back against such nonsense. And if one employer doesn't like Jews, it is easier to find another who will hire them.

Comment: https://www.timesofisrael.com/how-holocaust-survivors-flocked-to-nj-to-start-a-thriving-poultry-farming-industry/amp/

Comment: https://footnote.wordpress.ncsu.edu/2020/06/11/the-jewish-agricultural-society-06-12-2020/ , https://www.jstor.org/stable/3742724 , and https://sites.rutgers.edu/jewish-agriculture/a-world-of-jewish-farming/ may interest you.

Comment: My thoughts without sources: Centuries ago, Eastern European Jews were often forbidden to live in major cities, therefore, they mostly resided in smaller towns and villages. When in the 19th century restrictions on Jews owning land (and living in cities too) were lifted, many of them started to engage in farming and opened agricultural factories. However, in the US it was exactly the opposite. Jews were arriving in major coastal cities, and if they'd wanted to move to rural areas, they'd have needed to convince a bunch of other Jews to move with them to be able to live a religious life.

Comment: On the other hand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Dov_Weissmandl#Establishment_of_an_American_yeshiva

Comment: @msh210 Great links, good reads. Looks like the farming situation changed in the 1970s so people stopped promoting farming.

Comment: @ClintEastwood "...strongly encourage their employees to be Christians??" Maybe if they work for Catholic Charities or the local Christian food bank. That's not middle America now. The same laws that protect Noahides and Muslims and Atheists from religious discrimination also protect Jews. It's true there a lot more employers in the cities.

Comment: @Dude Valid points. I'm just saying, if your family never has to buy eggs or basic vegetables, and you sell your extras, Your cost to live drops significantly while your quality of life improves. Less money spent on housing and food could pay for the staff of an epic day school.

Comment: @Kazibácsi But Jews aren't just in coastal cities. It seems like they only setup synagoges in congested urban areas with high populations. The midwest hasn't had any pro-palestinian marches. You could own a peaceful field to go out for hitbodedut. Grow some of your own food. Personally, I'd like to see synagogues in the midwest.

Comment: There are many rural Jewish communities in USA, UK, Australia. E.g. https://www.nytimes.com/2000/08/18/us/a-synagogue-rises-in-rural-america.html. Not sure your premise is correct, it seems people have been having those ideas for a while and going for it

Comment: @RabbiKaii That article is 24 years old. Yes, there have been articles about it. But I look at the OU Synagogue Finder https://www.ou.org/synagogue-finder/  and they're just not out there. Or the synagogues aren't mapped. 5 cities in all of Texas? Anything in Kansas is centered on Kansas City.  Anything in Missouri is centered on St. Louis.  One synagogue in Oklahoma. One in Nebraska. One in Kentucky. Where's ONE rural community in real life in the USA? Where are 'they going for it' at? Even in Portland the lone farmer had to commute in an RV over Shabbat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Farming is very hard and involves a lot of risk. If a city Jew takes his net worth and converts it to land, equipment, and seed and doesn't make enough profit to live on and buy next year's seed, he's ruined.

Its hard for people who have been farmers for generations and will be near impossible for someone with no experience to start.

Farmers work as long as work is needed and can't afford to keep Shabbat, pop off for mincha, or study Torah.

In short: American Jews don't farm because of high barriers to enter the profession, high risk, and impediments to live the Torah lifestyle. Food prices are far lower than they were in biblical times and you can't make a profit unless you have a huge farm.

Comment: Also, Jews are not allowed to castrate animals or graft trees.

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. Farms are changing and small-scale organic and locally-produced food does quite well. A free-range chicken will lay 5 eggs a week reliably for 2 years, and require less than 15 minutes of care a day. Trying to get rich farming is very hard. Feeding your family and local community is entirely different.